# Python, Json - get_wiki_main_image doesn't return a link for img

Tags: python, json

Why doesn't the script below return a photo url link? I try to modify the code but it has no effect.

```
import requests
import json

def get_wiki_main_image(title):
    url = 'https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamek_Kr%C3%B3lewski_na_Wawelu'
    data = {
        'action' :'query',
        'format' : 'json',
        'formatversion' : 2,
        'prop' : 'pageimages|pageterms',
        'piprop' : 'original',
        'titles' : title
    }
    response = requests.get(url, data)
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    return json_data['query']['pages'][0]['original']['source'] if len(json_data['query']['pages']) >0 else 'Not found'
    urllink = get_wiki_main_image('zamek królewski na wawelu')
    print (urllink)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: That response.get() is returning HTML, not JSON. At least it does when I attempt against that URL. The `json.loads(response.text)` errors as a result. Are you getting back json? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I run it with CMD command: python file.py
`file.py - saved script`

How do I return get_wiki_main_image to see it in the CMD console?

Comment: How am I supposed to run the file? What am I supposed to pass in the function `get_wiki_main_image`?

Answer (score 0):

By observation, we notice that all the pictures in Wikipedia are in the folder https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb. If without using additional libraries:

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamek_Kr%C3%B3lewski_na_Wawelu')

gen = r.iter_lines()   # create a byte string generator
for s in gen:
    # Is there such a substring, with the folder we need, in this line
    if s.find(b'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb') == -1:
        continue
    else:
        ss = s.split(b'"')   # split the byte string to separate the url
        print(ss[3].decode('utf-8'))   # take the url and convert it to a string
```

Console output:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Royal_Castle%2C_Wawel_Hill%2C_4_Wawel%2C_Old_Town%2C_Krak%C3%B3w%2C_Poland.jpg/1200px-Royal_Castle%2C_Wawel_Hill%2C_4_Wawel%2C_Old_Town%2C_Krak%C3%B3w%2C_Poland.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Royal_Castle%2C_Wawel_Hill%2C_4_Wawel%2C_Old_Town%2C_Krak%C3%B3w%2C_Poland.jpg/800px-Royal_Castle%2C_Wawel_Hill%2C_4_Wawel%2C_Old_Town%2C_Krak%C3%B3w%2C_Poland.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Royal_Castle%2C_Wawel_Hill%2C_4_Wawel%2C_Old_Town%2C_Krak%C3%B3w%2C_Poland.jpg/640px-Royal_Castle%2C_Wawel_Hill%2C_4_Wawel%2C_Old_Town%2C_Krak%C3%B3w%2C_Poland.jpg
```

There are three static pictures on the site with different sizes.